# FlexSlider full-width display

Tags: slider

I don't seem to be able to get rid of a white margin of some 5px around FlexSlider set to width:100%.

I've set all the paddings and margins to 0px and even tried tweeking the js plugin itself, without much luck.

Anybody?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The class `.flexslider` has a border of 4 or 5px (white). Set this border to none to get rid of it in your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

nop it was not that,
remove the following line form flexslider.css, I believe is in line 66:

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next { 
    right: -50px; 
    text-align: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it. Too easy. Just disable the FlexSlider css and set the flexslider div to position:absolute; left:0px;